# Looping through nested arrays and reordering them in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through nested arrays and reorder them into new nested arrays. For example, take [[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], [i,j,k,l]] and change it into [[a,e,i], [b,f,j], [c,g,k], [d,h,l]]

```
let rowArr = [[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], [i,j,k,l]];
let newRowArr = [];
    let length = rowArr.length;
    for(let i = 0; i<length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j<rowArr.length; j++){
            newRowArr.push(rowArr[i][j]);
            j+=rowArr.length;
            }
console.log(newRowArr) //I get only [a,e,i]
```

I am missing something obvious but why won't it loop the additional times to push the other letters into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the nested loop where `i` and `j` are names for outer in inner index names and then use them to add to new array as `result[j][i] = current inner loop value`

```js
let arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
  ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
];

const result = []

arr.forEach((a, i) => {
  a.forEach((e, j) => {
    if (!result[j]) result[j] = []
    result[j][i] = e
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
let rowArr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']];
let newRowArr = [];
let arraySize = 4;

const arrayColumn = (arr, n) => arr.map(x => x[n]);

for (let i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
  newRowArr.push(arrayColumn(rowArr, i));
}

console.log(newRowArr);
```